# Video does not play with an async observable call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a video element in an html file, when I set the source parameter string it plays perfectly, but when I pass the value trough an observable async call the video does not play no matter the selector gets the correct src value.
This is my code:

```
<div class="modal" [ngClass]="{'is-active':isActive}">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-card">
        <header class="modal-card-head">
            <p class="modal-card-title">{{(info$ | async).name}}</p><button class="delete" (click)="onClose()" aria-label="close"></button></header>
        <section class="modal-card-body">
            <p>{{(info$ | async).url}}</p><video id="video" controls="controls"><source [src]="(info$ | async).url" type="video/mp4"/></video></section>
        <footer class="modal-card-foot"></footer>
    </div><button class="modal-close is-large"></button></div>
```

Just to mention that all other async observable calls works but the video call does not

Comment: Are there any messages in the browser console?

Comment: no, there is not any error message, warning or advice